# PERL: repeated lines

Tags: perl

I'm writing a perl code that print a massage/send a mail if there is a repeated line found in a file.
My code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
my %prv_line;
open(FILE, "somefile") || die "$!";
while(<FILE>){
    if($prv_line{$_}){
         $prv_line{$_}++;
     }
    #my problem: print  I saw this line X times
    }
close FILE
```

My problem: How do generate a static msg with output: print "I saw this line X times" without printing the script output 
Thanks

Comment: what does static msg means ? you wan't to auto-generate code ?, 
or also without printing output , requirements are not really clear.

Comment: What im trying to solve: coutn the lines and print how many times it appeared : print " 6 lines where found duplicate"# sorry for my English

Comment: @Raid5 You should know that deduping with hash keys will only perform a lexically exact dedupe, not a logical dedupe. For example: `if($foo)  {` will not be considered a duplicate of `if ($foo) {`  (different whitespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code is very close. Well done for `use strict` and putting `$!` in the `die` string. You should also always `use warnings`, use the three-parameter form of `open`, and use lexical file handles.

This program should help you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %prv_line;
open (my $FILE, '<', 'somefile') || die $!;
while (<$FILE>) {
  if ( $prv_line{$_} ) {
    print "I saw this line $prv_line{$_} times\n";
  }
  $prv_line{$_}++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

probably, here's what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %lines;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    $lines{$_}++; 
}

while (my($key, $value) = each %lines) {
    print "I saw the line '$key' $value times\n";
}

__DATA__
abc
def
def
def
abc
blabla

avaddv

bla
abc
```

Of course, it can be improved.

Comment: You probably only want to print one count.